# copying the same thing on same context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a problem with jquery i have 2 different set of icons which of each i want to the same thing:

### My primary codes are

```
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          </a>
      </li>

       <li>
          <a href="">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

### what i want after loading on my browse

```
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          </a>
      </li>

       <li>
          <a href="">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

### i have tried to use

```
var socials = $("ul a");
socials.each(function ( index,elem ){
    var jumpIcons = $( this ).find("i");
    socials.append(jumpIcons);
});
```

### but the result is browser is hangged :'(

Comment: please explain, what you need exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clone and add the element to the current `a`

```
var socials = $("ul a");
socials.each(function (index, elem) {
    var jumpIcons = $(this).find("i");
    //first you need to clone the current element else, you are just repositioning the current `i` elemnet
    //then you need to append it to the current a element, not to all `a` element in the socials - this will cause a lot of iteration if there a lot of `ul a` elements in the page resulting in unresponisve page
    $(this).append(jumpIcons.clone());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vujp7zob/)

---

A simplified version

```
var socials = $("ul a");
socials.append(function (index, elem) {
    return $(this).find("i").clone();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vujp7zob/2/)

Comment: i have another question:
when i want to hover on i:first-child it would go to top:-42px and last -child wiil go to top:0px . how can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `clone()`, see below code

```
var socials = $("ul a");
socials.each(function ( index,elem ){
    var jumpIcons = $( this ).find("i").clone();//make clone of i
    $(this).append(jumpIcons);// use $(this) to get current element
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `clone` that `i` for each `a` with all the `events` of it(if needed) and `append` it to `a`. Try with -

```
var socials = $("li a");
socials.each(function ( index, elem ){
    var jumpIcons = $( this ).find("i").clone(true, true); //remove true, true if you dont need the events
    $(this).append(jumpIcons);
});
```